# $f\in L^p(X,\mu)$ , $f-1\in L^q(X,\mu)$ then $\mu(X) < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Can some one give a hint how to start to solve :

> Assume $ 1 \le p,q < \infty $ and $$f\in L^p(X,\mu)$$ now if we assume $$f-1\in L^q(X,\mu)$$ then we have $$\mu (X) < \infty $$

Thanks

If $|f|$ or $|f-1|$ has a positive infimum $m$ then problem is solved because:

$ m^p \mu(X)^p < (\int_{X} |f|^p \,\ dx)< \infty $

Comment: For the lebesgue measure $\mu$ an idea could be like this. $f\in L^p$ means roughly(!), that $f$ decays to zero far out. $f-1\in L^q$ means roughly(!), that $f$, tends to one far outside. However, the function that is approximately $1$ far outside can not be in $L^p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality (exchanging $f$ and $f-1$) we can assume $q\geq p$.

We are given that $$\infty>\int|f|^p=\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|f|^p+\int_{\{|f|^p\geq 1\}}|f|^p$$

Since $M\mu(\{|f|^p\geq M\})\leq\left|\int_{\{|f|^p\geq M\}}|f|^p\right|$, in particular $$\mu(\{|f|^p\geq 1\})<\infty$$

Now $$\infty>\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|f|^p\geq\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|f|^q$$

By Minkowsky's inequality

$$\begin{align}\mu(\{|f|^p<1\})^{1/q}&=\left(\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}1\right)^{1/q}\\&=\left(\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|f+1-f|\right)^{1/q}\\&\leq\left(\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|f|^q\right)^{1/q}+\left(\int_{\{|f|^p<1\}}|1-f|^q\right)^{1/q}\\&<\infty\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$\mu(X)=\mu(\{|f|^p<1\})+\mu(\{|f|^p\geq 1\})<\infty.$$